# Issue with formatting headers that automatically include section titles

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using a template for an assignment. it's supposed to put the section title and the subsection titles in  the header, but they're overlapping, and it looks dreadful.

These are the bits of the preamble that look relevant:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{extramarks} % For headers and footers
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{gensymb}


% Margins
\geometry{
a4paper,
tmargin=1in,
bmargin=1in,
lmargin=1in,
rmargin=1in,
textwidth=6.5in,
textheight=9.0in,
headsep=0.25in
}

% Header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\lhead{\myName} % Top left header
%\chead{\myCourse}%: \myAssignment} % Top center header
%\rhead{\firstxmark} % Top right header
\lfoot{\lastxmark} % Bottom left footer
\cfoot{} % Bottom center footer
\rfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \pageref{LastPage}} % Bottom right footer
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt} % Size of the header rule
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt} % Size of the footer rule
```

[image: What my header looks like]

The headings should be '3.2 Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a 3D matrix' and '3 CALCULATING EIGENVALUES AND EIGENVECTORS'.

How do I fix this so they appear separately, or get rid of the subsections and just leave the chapters/sections?

Comment: Your titles are just too long to fit in a single line. Perhaps you could add a linebreak?

Comment: `\section[short title]{long title not for toc or page head}`

Comment: If you add `twoside` to the `\documentclass` (like `\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}`, the section and subsection titles will go to different pages.